Incorrect reference returned to a static instance of a structure via getter function when getter is inlined
I have a following structure of a code.
Basically, I am initialising a static instance of a structure via an initialization function, and then retrieving a reference to it via a getter function. The issues is that when I define the getter in dummy.hpp as an inlined function the values contained within structure returned are incorrect.
dummy.hpp
struct MyStruct
{
    int iVal{};
    double dVal{};

    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const MyStruct & obj){
        os << obj.iVal << " " << obj.dVal << std::endl;
        return os;
    }
};

static MyStruct myStruct;

void initMyStruct(const MyStruct & rhs);
//MyStruct &getMyStruct(); // <-- works when definition moved to dummy.cpp
inline MyStruct &getMyStruct() {
     return myStruct;
}

dummy.cpp
#include "dummy.hpp"
void initMyStruct(const MyStruct & rhs)
{
    myStruct.iVal = rhs.iVal;
    myStruct.dVal = rhs.dVal;    
}

//MyStruct &getMyStruct() {
//    return myStruct;
//}

main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "dummy.hpp"
int main()
{
    MyStruct strct{10, 15.5};
    initMyStruct(strct);
    std::cout << getMyStruct() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Expected output: 10 15.5
Actual Output: 0 0
However, moving the definition to dummy.cpp solves the problem and the returned structure has correct value.
I strongly suspect that having a static instance of the structure is behind this? Is this static initialization order fiasco? Declaring getMyStruct() as consteval did not solve the problem. Any insights would be greatly helpful.

static MyStruct myStruct; in global scope means myStruct's scope is limited to a translation unit. Since it is in dummy.hpp which is included in both dummy.cpp and main.cpp, each cpp has its own copy.

Making the variable inline instead of static would help. But as there already is a .cpp file, it might be better to just move it there, as having a getter for a global variable seems a bit odd.

Thank you. This answered my question: link . But, why did separating the definition and the declaration solved the problem without declaring myStruct as extern?
